# Remove joists from above the kitchen

Tags: joists

I have installed skylights and would like to cut through the ceiling. I have taken some pics from the attic. Would I be able to cut the joists above my kitchen and have the vaulted ceiling show up? When I checked the attic the joists does not seem to be connected to the 2 Nd floor. I have taken as much as pics as possible. Any help or advice is appreciated thanks

https://photos.app.goo.gl/BpcbTq1ALxc98nTh8

Comment: You don't have joists....you have trusses!   Please do not cut the trusses without approval from a Structural Engineer.

Comment: @LimoDRIVER  It does seem like he has joists and trusses(odd), but your advice is still needed for him to get a structural engineer.

Comment: I saw the joists hidden, but more importantly the trusses would  need to be removed to expose the skylights, unless he just wanted to frame each skylight individually and have 2 shafts of light up to the roof.    At first I thought joists probably just support the drywall only, but then saw the trusses being supported by the on top of the plywood in some places, but not others.